# Passing values between multiple pages php

Tags: php

I am using 2 pages. Page 1, the user enters name and age. I have given form action as the same page and user selects either one or both occupation and the data gets pushed to page 2 which displays all the results. Below is the code for the same:

Page1:

```
<?php
echo "<form action=\"page1.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<h2>Your Name.  *</h2><input type='text' name='user_name'>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<h2>Your Age.  *</h2><input type='text' name='age'>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<div><input type='submit' value='Review'></div>";

?>

<?php
if((empty($_POST['user_name'])) || (empty($_POST['age'])) ) {
    echo "<h2>Please enter your user name and age</h2>";
} else {
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    echo "<h2>Below are the details entered:</h2><br>";
    echo "<h2>Name: </h2>$user_name";
    echo "<h2>Age: </h2>$age";
    echo "<form action=\"page2.php\" method=\"post\">";
    echo '<td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="color:#003399"><input type="checkbox" 
      name="occupation[]" value="QA">QA</td>';
    echo '<td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="color:#003399"><input type="checkbox" 
      name="occupation[]" value="Tester">Tester</td>';
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value='Add to DB' >";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Page2:

```
<?php
$user_name = $_GET['user_name'];
$age = $_GET['junos_version'];
$occupation = $_GET['occupation'];
echo "<h2>Below are the details entered:</h2><br>";
echo "<h2>Name: </h2>$user_name";
echo "<h2>Age: </h2>$age";
echo "<h2>Occupation selected: </h2>";
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($occupation);$i++) {
    echo "  $occupation[$i]  ";
}   
?>
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Your acceptance record is rather questionable. Stack isn't a "one way street".

Comment: Done!!! I have accepted answers for my previous questions... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all of that fields in just one form and validate the action or put validation into php before frontend start, I prefer the first one to your case, it's easier:

**FILTERING IN THE ACTION**

```
<?php
 if (empty($_POST['user_name'])){
       $action = 'page1.php';
       $structure = "<h2>Please enter your user name and age</h2>";
       $submit = 'Review';
  } else {
       $action = 'page2.php'; 
       $phrase = '';
       $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
       $age = $_POST['age'];
       $structure = '<h2>Below are the details entered:</h2><br>
                     <h2>Name: </h2>$user_name
                      <h2>Age: </h2>$age
                       <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="color:#003399"><input type="checkbox" name="occupation[]" value="QA">QA</td>
                       <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="color:#003399"><input type="checkbox" name="occupation[]" value="Tester">Tester</td>';
echo "<br>";
       $submit = 'Add to DB';
  }

echo "<form action='{$action}' method=\"post\">";
echo "<h2>Your Name.  *</h2><input type='text' name='user_name'>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<h2>Your Age.  *</h2><input type='text' name='age'>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo $structure;
echo "<div><input type='submit' value='{$submit}'></div>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

PS: Avoid all those echoes, put just plain html and use php where it needed, it's better. TD's outside tables are utterly wrong, remove then, use divs instead and organize them with CSS.